# .htaccess won't work syntax issue I suppose

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /newplace/ [L]
```

I want evrything from public_html for those who use browser listed above to be shown content from another location.
Now, the problem is in the line four and I don't know how to make it work... Anyhelp please...

There is still problem I put exaclly your code and there is still problem it says 500 Internal Server Error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will cause loop since it is redirecting to `/newplace/` for listed browsers.

Try this code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^((?!newplace/).*)$ /newplace/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry there was typo, try it now.

Comment: Still not working but differnt error message: 

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Are you shure .* should not be used in this process?

Comment: You need to tell whether 500 is gone or not. `.*` has no use in this rule.

Comment: Still not working but differnt error message: Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That means you haven't posted full .htaccess code in the question.

Comment: It is full htaccess cod, no other code or .htaccess files in above levels

Comment: Yes but `Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request` means that somewhere `ErrorDocument` directive has been used.

Comment: Strange, no meter what file I type it will always open newplace/index... any idea your code used

Comment: I didn't find the solution but you put a lot of your effort, so I mark you as successful answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for acceptance. I have modified the answer now to open `/newplace/file.html` when you request `/file.html` from listed browsers.

Comment: Your code above work if it is in public_html and directory from where files are taken in the first one in the line. Problem is if you want to put .htaccess file in lower level of directory example:   first/second/newplace/ and if you put .htaccess in second directory it won't work... any idea...

Comment: If you put in sub directory then remove leading `/` from target like `RewriteRule ^((?!newplace/).*)$ newplace/$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Can you look in this new question I put a link here, just follow it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704271/htaccess-file-all-others-whoa-re-not-some-browser

Answer (score 0):

You redirect every request to the folder `/newplace/`. You want something like this

```
RewriteRule (.*) /newplace/$1 [L]
```

The `$1` part will use the match from your rule.

Comment: The 500 error maybe elsewhere in your .htaccess file. Maybe you are not allowed to use Rewrite by your provider. Maybe mod-rewrite is not installed. You should check the apache log file.

Comment: mod rewrite is allow, there is no other .htaccess files and that is the nly code..