# .htaccess file all others whoa re not some browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (navigator) [NC]
RewriteRule ^newfolder/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

I em intresting in first line - How to put ALL OTHERS BROWSERS WHO ARE NOT NAVIGATOR? Somethung like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (navigator) [NC] ALL OTHERS WHO ARE NOT NAVIGATOR!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negation in `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(opera|navigator|safari) 
RewriteRule ^newfolder/(.*)$ /index.html [L,NC]
```

PS; Take note of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !navigator` which means all user agents except `navigator`.

Comment: It works with !navigator but when I try RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (!opera|!navigator|!safari) [NC] than it' not working... Is it bad sytax perhaps?